# why i'm getting error: no match for ‘operator<<?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

I'm beginner in programming and learning about vectors in c++ right now.I want to display the address of first element of vector
with the use subscript and with pointer.**Program 1** is working fine but I'm getting compilation error in **program 2**-

`error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘int’)
        cout<<*(num+1)<<endl;`

Program 1:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
   vector<int> num;
   //Enter the numbers

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     num.push_back(i);


   //Display address of first element using subscript
   cout<<&num[1]<<endl;


   return 0;
 }
```

Program 2:
 All codes are same except in place of subscript I want to display address with the help of pointer.

```
 //Display address of first element using pointer

   cout<<*(num+1)<<endl;
```

I also tried

```
cout<<(num.begin()+1)<<endl;
```

but it is showing same error .

Comment: A `std::vector` is not a pointer and does not provide an `operator+`. therefore `num+1` makes no sense

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. You are trying to add `std::vector` and `1`. You problably want to do something like `num.data() + 1`.

Comment: `//Display address of first element using subscript ... cout<<&num[1]<<endl;` your comment is lying. `num[1]` is not the first element.

Comment: num[0] is the zeroth element @Swordfish

Comment: @user4156958 roflmao

Answer (score 2):

`a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)` only when applied to pointers. (And to arrays, since they're automatically converted to pointers in this case.)

`std::vector` is not a pointer. It's a class (a class template, to be precise). Normally `[]` doesn't work on classes, but `std::vector` *overloads* operator `[]`, which means that it provides a special member function that's executed when `[]` is used on it.

But `std::vector` doesn't overload `+`, thus `+` can't be applied to vectors.

If you were to write your own `vector`, you could easily overload `+` to behave as you want it to.

Comment: i also tried to do this `cout<<(num.begin()+1)<<endl;` but it is showing same error.

Comment: @user4156958 Because `num.begin()` returns an *iterator*, not a pointer. After adding `1` to it it remains an iterator. `std::cout` doesn't know how to print iterators. If you want to get a pointer to the first element of the vector, use `num.data()` as suggested in comments under your question.

Comment: @Swordfish thanks. then `num.data()+1` is all there is to it. I really need to get some sleep.

Comment: Although correct, for the sake of completeness I would mention that `std::vector` is not a class but a template container class which is instantiated for the given type.